# HTML output is rendered improperly, Any ideas why?

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, datatable

I am using spring 2.5.6, hibernate and jsp.

I have started to improve quality of the data tables.

I have changed some of the jsp files from display tag to jquery datatable. But, one page goes mad. Although everything is same with other pages, there occurs a damn problem with this page...
See here:

[image: Many non-alphanumeric characters in a browser]

Code is as below:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@include file="/common/taglibs.jsp"%>
<%@include file ="/WEB-INF/pages/dataTableUtil.jsp"%>

<head>
<title><fmt:message key="workDemandsAssignedByGroupChiefList.title"/></title>
<content tag="heading"><fmt:message key="workDemandsAssignedByGroupChiefList.heading"/></content>
<meta name="menu" content="WorkDemandsAssignedByGroupChiefList"/>
<style>
    /*    .margins
        {
            margin-left: 8px;
            margin-top: 8px;
            margin-right:  8px;
            margin-bottom: 8px;
        }*/
    .textFontSyle
    {
        color: #ac2925;

    }
</style>

</head>

<c:out value="${buttons}" escapeXml="false"/>
<strong><fmt:message key="workDemandsAssignedByGroupChiefList.heading"/></strong>



<table id="example" style="font-size: 110%" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Talep No</th>
            <!--<th>Talep Durumu</th>-->
            <!--            <th>Talep Eden Kullanıcı</th>-->
            <!--<th>Talep Türü</th>-->
            <!--<th>Özet Açıklama</th>-->
            <!--            <td></td>-->
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Talep No</th>
            <!--<th>Talep Durumu</th>-->
            <!--            <th>Talep Eden Kullanıcı</th>-->
            <!--<th>Talep Türü</th>-->
            <!--<th>Özet Açıklama</th>-->
            <!--            <td></td>-->
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${workDemandList}">

            <tr>
                <td> 
                    <c:out value="${item.id}" escapeXml="true" />
                </td>


            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: "workDemandList" is the List returned by corresponding controller.

Comment: Define `improve the quality`? You are now including xml apparently I suspect that that braks you page...

Comment: By saying "improve the quality" I mean, filling a table with "display tag library" it acts slow. User cannot search record. So I decided to remove "display tags" and fill the table via jquery datatable. Which part did I include Xml?

Comment: Although you can implement searching with display tag (quite easy btw) you might want to take a look at the [datatables](https://datatables.net/development/server-side/jsp) which is a lot newer.

Answer (score 0):

it is about browser encoding. A filter try to compress your data. You can search it as gzip encoding. You should manage your browser encoding filters.